# How to get the min value of an array excluding 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 are user decelerated variables, the user can chose between 0 and 5.
I want to get the minimum value of those 5 variables but if one or more of those is a 0 i want to get excluded the one(s) that are 0.

```
var array = new[] { x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 };  
int minarray = array.Min();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter out all the values that are zero with `Where`.

```
int min = array.Where(x => x != 0).Min();
```

However if all the values are zero that will result in an exception so instead you could do this

```
int min = array.Where(x => x != 0).DefaultIfEmpty().Min();
```

However that will result in 0 when all the values are 0, which seems reasonable.